# How to pull plugin from github on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git@github.com:mdrozdziel/paperclip.git'
...
```

While pushing the app I get the following error. The repo I am linking to is public.

```
Fetching git@github.com:mdrozdziel/paperclip.git
   Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/group_home/.ssh/known_hosts).
   Permission denied (publickey).
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "git@github.com:mdrozdziel/paperclip.git" "/disk1/tmp/build_28099_23931178722320/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-c032df0dc0463697a1ce5ae3761bec95be700815" --bare --no-hardlinks. Cannot complete bundling.
```

Any idea what is the problem here? Console shows that /home/group_home/ does not exists...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems the :git param you're providing is causing bundler to try to pull it over ssh.  You'll need to use a public repository address.  Try the following instead:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/mdrozdziel/paperclip.git'
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved a problem I was having with Spree (I'd also added the gem using the git@github syntax)